# Does LLVM's JIT engines use the system linker (ld)?

Tags: llvm, jit

I've been reading about LLVM and clang and I understand that the LLVM framework generates object files for the target machine and the system linker (ld, for linux) does the dynamic linking.

But I don't understand how things work when JIT compilation takes place. Is the system linker still invoked in this case? I see that there is a RuntimeDyld.cpp file. Is it to link between different bitcode files being JIT compiled, or does it link to other shared libraries that are loaded dynamically?

Comment: A one line comment explaining the down vote would help me improve the question. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, it's using `ld.so` functionality (on Linux and alikes), namely, `dlopen`, `dlsym`, etc.